# Media files are not visible after deploying the django project on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, file, heroku, deployment

I have deployed my website (build in django) on heroku, all the static files are visible but media files are not showing.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Please improve your question with details on what you want to achieve, what did you research, what did you try to fix your problem and where/how are you stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You might be lacking a media config in `settings.py`. To learn how to do it you can [go to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT). Basically you would need something like this in said file:

> MEDIA_ROOT Default: '' (Empty string)
>
> Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold [user-uploaded
> files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/).
>
> Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, can you add your `settings.py` media config? Also say what your real path is for example `home/root/app/src/media`.

Comment: Alright, let me try the way you suggested. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: @Tushar_K no worries, if it works you can mark it as an answer, if it doesn't, put more info and/or errors.